# How to get the file location from online drives and use it in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

There is a situation to get the location of the file from drive, and I need to use the file location in Jmeter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Most cloud storage services come with tooling that mounts the drive somewhere in your local filesystem, you should be able to access the files like any other file on your computer.

Now in jMeter just point to this local file path.

As you do not specify which "online drive" you are using, I would Google for something like: mount (replace with your cloud storage provider) as local drive

Or use a tool like: http://www.netdrive.net/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that all online drives solutions have APIs allowing building client programs and manipulating data programmatically. From JMeter you can use 2 options:

1. SOAP or REST API. Both are HTTP-based and you will be able to use JMeter's [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to execute API call.
2. Java API. JMeter is a pure Java application and it provides [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) which is capable of executing arbitrary [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) code (valid Beanshell code in 99% of cases is valid Java code). So you can:

   - download your online drive Java Client API library (usually .jar file)
   - copy .jar file(s) to /lib folder of your JMeter installation
   - using Beanshell Sampler develop code to locate the file on the online drive
   - use the file location in JMeter script or wherever you need it.

Look for documentation on SOAP/REST or Java API for your online drive for details on method to access file location and see [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide to learn more on Beanshell scripting specifics in Jmeter.